# Distribution of a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I've been asked to determine the distribution of $\int_0^t h(s) \, dW_s$ where $h$ is a deterministic function of one variable, $W$ is brownian.

My thoughts were

$$
\int_0^t h(s) \, dW_s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{\pi (n)} h(t_i)(W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}) = Z
$$

Where $\pi (n)$ is some partition. Now I know that $W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}$ is normal distributed, and a sum (finite?) of normal distributed is normal.

I calculated $E[Z] = 0$ and for the variance I need $E[Z^2]$,

$$
E[Z^2] = E\left[\left(\int_{0}^{t} h(s) \, dW_s \right)^2 \right]
$$

Now **if** $h \in L^2$ then by Ito Isometry

$$
E[Z^2] = E\left[\left(\int_0^t h(s) \, dW_s \right)^2 \right] = \int_0^t E[h^2(s)] \, ds = \int_0^t h^2(s) \, ds = V
$$

Thus I want to conclude that $Z \sim N(0,V)$

Comment: Any distributional limit of normal distribution is also (possibly degenerate) normal. Since the stochastic integral converges in $L^2$-sense (and each Riemann sum is normal since it is a linear combination of jointly normal variables), it converges in distribution and thus the integral is also normal. So you only need to determine two parameters, namely mean and variance.